# query array particular array elements in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

I have collection of

```
{array:[1,2,3]},
{array:[1,2,4]},
{array:[2,1,2]}
```

How to return all objects where array has

```
[1,2,*anyNumber]
```

to get result

```
{array:[1,2,3]},
{array:[1,2,4]},
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You could include in your question, what you have tried so far so that we could say why the code you have tried doesn't give you the correct result. You need to have a look at the mongodb `$in` query operator.

Comment: thanks, I tried $all but didnt work

Comment: Do you need the elements to be in that particular order ? For example, consider a doc {array:[2,1,5]}. Should this be returned too or not ?

Comment: yes it needs to be in particular order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ordering to be exactly the same, i.e. first element to be 1 and second element to be 2, then use

```
db.coll.find({"array.0": 1, "array.1": 2})
```

However, this will also return docs where there is no element at index 3. If you want the third element to be present, use this:

```
db.coll.find({"array.0": 1, "array.1": 2, "array.2": {"$exists": true}})
```

Also, this will return arrays whose length can be greater than 3. If you are specifically looking for arrays whose length is 3 only, then you may use `$where` to check the length

```
db.coll.find({"array.0": 1, "array.1": 2, "array.2": {"$exists": true}, $where:'this.array.length==3'})
```

If this is complicated and you are just looking for documents where array contains 1 and 2 irrespective of the ordering and irrespective of presence of a third element, then simply use:

```
db.coll.find({"array": {"$all": [1,2]}})
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!